# raspbian qt virtual keyboard black top screen

Tags: python, qt, raspbian, qtvirtualkeyboard

I run Qt Virtual Keyboard example in ubuntu and windows 10 very nice, but on raspbian it runs just on full screen mode and i can not see text edit when typing with virtual keyboard. I want virtual keyboard width fit to window size and show under the text edit. How ?

```
import sys
import os
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

os.environ["QT_IM_MODULE"] = "qtvirtualkeyboard"

app = QApplication([])
w = QWidget()
vl = QVBoxLayout(w)
btn = QPushButton()
btn.setText('Start')
vl.addWidget(btn)
tb = QLineEdit()
vl.addWidget(tb)

w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

result on windows 10:

[image]

but on raspbian it look like:

[image]

how can i solve it? 
please help

Comment: This solution fixed it for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/63963718/594323

Answer (score 0):

I've the same Problem. (QT 5.11.3) This looks exactly like this Bug:

- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54088
- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56357

A suggested Workaround is to set the Color of the QQuickWindow to transparent. e.g.

```
QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(YourRootQuickObj );

QSurfaceFormat surfaceFormat = window->requestedFormat();
surfaceFormat.setAlphaBufferSize(8);
surfaceFormat.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);

window->setFormat(surfaceFormat);
window->setColor(QColor(Qt::transparent)); //Workaround
window->setClearBeforeRendering(true);

window->showFullScreen();
```

This Issue seems to be fixed in QT 5.15.  I'm currently building this version, i will report if this version will fix this Bug.

Comment: Im having the same problem with v5.15 too, but the following solution using a mask fixed it for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/63963718/594323

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered in [How to find the window that contains the QtVirtualKeyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63955568/how-to-find-the-window-that-contains-the-qtvirtualkeyboard) .

Using the code given in the mentioned post you just need to adjust "y" in:
`r.moveTop(keyboard->property("y").toDouble());`
you can also work with these attributes:

`r.setTop(250)`
`r.setRight(820)`
`r.setLeft(460)` 
Best of luck.